# Cannot use vector icon on wix navigation bar

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, velo, vector-icons

I can use vector icon everywhere but the navigation bar. It's display nothing.

```
rightButtons: [
        {
            icon: iconsMap['ios-home'], // This one not work
            id: 'add'
        },
        {
            icon: require('./../../assets/homeicon.png'), // this one work
            id: 'Test'
        },
    ],
```

Here is my full project
https://github.com/Knight1988/RNWixNavigationReduxStarter

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: hi, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/43, https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/2705